# create a Hyperledger Fabric network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Hyperledger Fabric community,
I am a beginner Hyperledger Fabric developer, I have some ambiguities regarding how a Hyperledger Fabric network works and is created.
So what is the use of the fabric-samples network and the test-network or first network and above all, what are the steps to follow to create, configure and launch a Hyperledger Fabric network
I need your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to [Getting Started](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/getting_started.html)

Use a Mac OS or Ubuntu platform and follow the instructions for installing and running the networks. The test-network example is a great starting point, as it covers all of the basic concepts. There are shell scripts there that will help you to create a new 2 peer network, as well as scripts to help you deploy some chaincode. There are a lot of concepts to learn, but just getting a network up and running and being able to run contract code will be a great start.

After you have got a network up and running, you should look at the shell scripts and see exactly which Hyperledger commands were used to create each artefact.